# MySQL query runs if included, but not if called with AJAX

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have a weirdly specific problem with MySQL and AJAX. I am trying to populate an overlay that appears when the user clicks on an image.

```
<!-- HTML -->
<img src="thePhoto.jpg" onclick="showStory(171)">
```

---

```
// JavaScript
function showStory(itemId){
     $.post("includes/stories.php", {item_id: itemId}, function(data){
          $("#overlay").prepend(data);
     })
}
```

---

```
// PHP
if($_POST["item_id"]){ 
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM item WHERE item_id = ".$_POST["item_id"];
     $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
     echo $sql;
     while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
          echo "query has run";
          echo $row["item_title"];
     }
}
```

When the user clicks on the image, the text of the query ($sql) appears on the page, but the other two echoes are not returned. It seems that the query just isn't running.

But if I *include* the exact same code, it *does* work. ("171" was the number contained in "$_POST['item_id']".) If I include this code on the page, all of the echoes are printed and appear correctly:

```
//PHP
$sql = "SELECT * FROM item WHERE item_id = 171";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
echo $sql;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
     echo "query has run";
     echo $row["item_title"];
}
```

I've confirmed that it is not because of a time delay while the query runs. I've confirmed that it is not because of the use of a POST variable. I've confirmed that it is not because of a quirk with jQuery; the same problem occurs whether I use jQuery or not.

I am at a loss. Why won't the MySQL query run when called with AJAX?

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). and did you do any basic debugging? `var_dump($_POST)` to see what was received by php?

Comment: Have you checked with the browser's debug tools if there are any errors on the AJAX call?

Comment: Yes. There are no errors of any sort.

Comment: You're using a static item_id 171 in the second example, what happens if you use that in your ajax?  You didn't respond to Marc regarding what debugging you have done or printing out $_POST.

Comment: Using "171" in the instead of a variable makes no difference. I tried that.

Comment: run firebug check ajax request is correctly sending data to backend page and check what is being returned.  My guess is you're not including $connection in your backend page so its not actually executing the sql and instead throwing an error. Unless of course you've not posted your whole code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are echo'ing 2 seperate things each time round a loop. That is likely confusing something somewhere. Also I am not sure you have a `<?php` at the top of the file?

Try running it from javascript after also removing the debug echo's

Looks like you may also be missing a database connection.

```
<?php
// PHP
// I think you may need to connect in this as a stand alone script
if(isset($_POST["item_id"])){ 
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM item WHERE item_id = ".$_POST["item_id"];
     $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
     if ( ! $result) {
        echo 'The query failed with error ' . mysql_error();
        exit;
     }

     $return = '';
     while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
          $return .= $row["item_title"];
     }
     echo $return;
} else {
     echo "An error occured item_id does not exist";
}
exit;
```

Alternative: It is quite possible that the query is only supposed to return one row because the `item_id` is unique on that table so try this if that is the case

```
<?php
// I think you may need to connect in this as a stand alone script
if(isset($_POST["item_id"])){ 
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM item WHERE item_id = ".$_POST["item_id"];
     $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
     if ( ! $result) {
        echo 'The query failed with error ' . mysql_error();
        exit
     }

     $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

     echo $row["item_title"];
} else {
     echo "An error occured item_id does not exist";
}
exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

TLDR; Your problem is in the post superglobal.

> When the user clicks on the image, the text of the query ($sql) appears on the page, but the other two echoes are not returned. It seems that the query just isn't running.

If you are seeing the first echo it means that the query has run. `mysqli_query` is what runs the query `mysqli_fetch_assoc` just grabs you the results. If you are not seeing the 2nd and 3rd echoes it means `mysqli_fetch_assoc`'s return value evaluates to false - if you look at the documentation of the function you will see it returns `false` only if there are no more records to fetch.

Keeping the above in mind, you say that hardcoding the value works, then doesn't that make you think that there may be something wrong with `$_POST["item_id"]`? Perhaps it is not the number you'd expect.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved! Thanks everyone.

The issue was the $connection variable. When I included the code on the page, it had access to the definition of $connection, which was defined further up the page. When I called it with AJAX, it was isolated from that definition and so $connection was null.

I have now defined $connection in its own file and included that file in the script which is being called by AJAX.

```
//PHP
include ("database.php");
if($_POST["item_id"]){ 
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM item WHERE item_id = ".$_POST["item_id"];
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    echo $row["item_title"];
}
```

Seems obvious in retrospect. I'm used to JavaScript, and I had forgotten that PHP would not retain the value of a variable after a script had finished running.

Answer (score -1):

Did you var_dump $result and $connection?
Is any other things make $connection is null?

Comment: Okay, there's something. $connection and $result are both null.